# Why does the jBPM demo run despite the xml file displaying errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, jbpm

I'm running the jBPM 6.0.1 demo (jbpm-installer/sample/evaluation) out of the box on Mavericks using `ant install.demo` and imported into Eclipse (Kepler). The project initially compiles and runs without any problems.

I then add a script node, that executes the Java line `System.out.println("foo");` [image]  When I run the file ProcessTest as a jUnit test, it successfully executes,

[image]

even though `targetNamespace` has been overridden to the empty string, and every line of the ioSpecification of every other nonterminal node registers an error.

[image]

I'm at a loss as to why this compiles successfully, never mind runs successfully. I've tried reinstalling my jBPM resources, no improvement.

Any idea what's going on?

-rsegal

Answer (score 1):

I believe you only have some configuration issues.

The XML file is probably valid, the problem lies within your IDE (that's why you can run the code but the editor shows some error). I suspect that it cannot link the XML to the DTD/XSD file, so it thinks that the XML is not valid.

The pictures are unfortunately so small that I cannot read what are the errors. Check the docs of your editor how to link these together (if it is Eclipse, you can play around with the *XML Catalog*, but I cannot tell you that from the picture).

Comment: That definitely seems to be the crux of the problem! I initially found the `schemaLocation` to be `http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd`, which I copied over to the `targetNamespace` and that resolved one error (of 17). However, the `schemaLocation` is now `http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd http://www.jboss.org/drools drools.xsd http://www.bpsim.org/schemas/1.0 bpsim.xsd`. Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: Yup, that seems a valid schema location for me. To make it easier, try `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`. If you Google it up, you'll find a lot of descriptions about how the namespace def for XML works, I believe this is will help you a bit.